# Add ID using JSON property

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops, html-table

I am looking to add in an ID for each row in the loop which will equal the data[i].name value. I have the data in a json structure which is reading as expected. I am struggling to find the correct place to add in the ID and also how to make sure the ID equals the data[i] name.

```
buildTable(myArray)

 function buildTable(data){
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable")

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
   var row = `<tr>  
                <td>${data[i].name}</td>
                <td>${data[i].theme}</td>
                <td>${data[i].level1}</td>
                <td>${data[i].level2}</td>
                <td>${data[i].level3}</td>
                <td> 
                  <select name="levels" id="levels">
                  <option value="level1">Level 1</option>
                  <option value="level2">Level 2</option>
                  <option value="level3">Level 3</option>
                  </select> 
                </td>
              </tr> `
  table.innerHTML += row
             }
  $("tr").addClass("class1")
 }
```

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Did you mean `<tr id="${data[i].name}">`?

Comment: Which property of `data[i]` do you want to use for the `id`? You seem to already know how to include information from `data[i]` in the HTML you're creating (that's what you're doing with `${data[i].name}` and such. Where are you stuck in relation to the `id`?

Comment: `<tr id="${data[i].name}">` should do the trick then already, no? (Whether all your names actually constitute _valid_ values for an id attribute, would be a different question.)

Comment: How are you going to use the ids? Rows in a table already have "id"s, they've `rowIndex` property.

Comment: Side note: Don't use `+=` with `innerHTML` in loop. When you do, each loop iteration the browser has to loop through all of the nodes in the element, build an HTML representation of them, hand that string to the JavaScript engine, get the updated string from the JavaScript engine, parse it, tear down the old elements and throw them away, build new elements, and fill in the target element with those new elements. Instead, use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) and similar (or create elements and `appendChild` them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```js
buildTable(myArray)

 function buildTable(data){
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable")
  var tableContent = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
   var row = `<tr id="${data[i].name}">  
                <td>${data[i].name}</td>
                <td>${data[i].theme}</td>
                <td>${data[i].level1}</td>
                <td>${data[i].level2}</td>
                <td>${data[i].level3}</td>
                <td> 
                  <select name="levels" id="levels">
                  <option value="level1">Level 1</option>
                  <option value="level2">Level 2</option>
                  <option value="level3">Level 3</option>
                  </select> 
                </td>
              </tr> `
  tableContent += row;
             }
  table.innerHTML = tableContent;
}
```